# Visual Studio Mac NETSDK1005

Tags: .net, visual-studio-mac

I have an existing project with UnitTests. When I build the unittests on my laptop, **Macbook M1**, I get the following error:

```
 Error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETFramework,Version=v5.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net50' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. (NETSDK1005)
```

The UnitTest project target framework is .NET 5.0 and builds and runs on my collegues latops.

If I create a new .net5.0 console application, it builds and runs fine on my laptop. When I add the same console application to my existing solution, I also get the error. Also, in the existing solution, the Micorsoft.NETCore.App framework disappears magically when opening the frameworks folder.

[image]

If I update the project to .NET 6 or 7 I get the same error about .NET 6 or 7.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: .NET 5 reached End-Of-Life almost a year ago. That means it's not supported *at all* any more. It was a single-year version from the start. The Long-Term-Support version is .NET 6, supported until 2024. If you installed VS for Mac recently, the installer would add either .NET 6 or .NET 7 (again a single-year version)

Comment: I know it is not supported anymore, the question is: why it runs in a new project but gives errors in an existing project and why the Microsoft.NETCore.App framework disappears.

Comment: Is the .NET 5 SDK installed at all? What does `dotnet --list-sdks` show?

Comment: No it's not, I think it is not possible on M1 (Arm64) processor either. Still, a new project with .NET 5.0 runs but in my existing project it doesn't, which is why I am confused.. And if I update my existing project to .NET 7.0 I get the same error about .NET 7.0 .NET 6.0.404 and 7.0.101 are currently installed.

Comment: `a new project with .NET 5.0 runs` that's probably a compiled binary that runs thanks to MacOS's x64 emulation. Just for experimentation, you can try [installing the x64 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/5.0) and try to use it through emulation. Don't expect things to work smoothly though - you'll be running a dead SDK  on an unsupported CPU architecture using emulation that's known to have issues. And all that to produce binaries for a dead runtime.

Comment: I just installed VS2019 Mac (intel) and there it builds and runs fine with .NET 5.0. The reason we can't update from .NET 5.0 is because it is part of a Xamarin.Forms project which does not work with .NET 6. We are planning to move to MAUI.

Comment: Do you have any classic projects in your solution? My guess is that the entire solution is being restored with MSBuild on Mono since. I would check Solution options - Build - General, and uncheck 'Build with MSBuild on Mono'.

Comment: Also worth checking what the dotnet path is in Preferences - Build and Debug - SDK Locations - .NET Core.

Comment: @MattWard Your solution "check Solution options - Build - General, and uncheck 'Build with MSBuild on Mono'" WORKS! You are my hero!!! You can post this as answer if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Assets file doesn't have a target framework for '.NET Framework,Version=v5.0'` error usually happens when MSBuild on Mono is being used to restore a solution in Visual Studio for Mac, and when MSBuild cannot find any supported .NET SDKs.

MSBuild on Mono does not support .NET SDKs 6.0.300 so Visual Studio for Mac downgrades to the oldest supported .NET SDK. In your case, on an Apple Silicon, it would likely be the case that MSBuild on Mono downgrades to no .NET SDK since the .NET 5 x64 SDK would be installed into a /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64 directory and not used.

MSBuild on Mono being used can happen if the solution contains any classic projects, which are non-SDK style projects.

To fix this problem open the Solution Options dialog, select Build - General, and uncheck `Build with MSBuild on Mono`. This will ensure the solution is restored with .NET not MSBuild on mono.

Classic projects will still be built with MSBuild on mono when this is unchecked. When it is checked the entire solution is restore and built with MSBuild on mono. This feature of using MSBuild mono was added to support classic Xamarin projects since using a mix of .NET and MSBuild can cause problems. One problem is with classic Xamarin.Forms projects which fail to build since the later .NET SDKs build the reference assemblies for the .NET Standard project into a folder that the classic MSBuild on mono is not expecting.